# link.download isn't downloading an image to desktop

Tags: javascript, save, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to save a file locally through JavaScript by using the `link.download = "";` command. What I'm trying to do is get an image stored on the server, and save it on the user's desktop. Here's my code:

```
function savePhoto(link){
    link.href = "img/profile01.jpg";
    link.download = "photo.jpg";
}
```

It opens the download dialog without a problem in FireFox and downloads well in Chrome. However, Internet Explorer 11 opens the image in the same window by putting the image address into the URL bar, instead of offering the Save File dialog.

**FireFox:**

[image: FireFox result works]

**IE 11:**

[image: IE 11 result doesn't work]

Is there a workaround for IE so I can offer the Save File dialog instead of showing the image in the browser?

Comment: According to this [web site](http://caniuse.com/download), IE does not support the download attribute.

Comment: Oh, wow. It looks like I'll also run into problems with Safari and iOS users. Time to start looking for a workaround!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Download property does not work in IE or even in Safari.

You might want to change the header with this:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf
```

huge_document.pdf would be your file name.

Here is a way you can do it with PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("huge_document.pdf");
?>
```

You might be able to just configure your server to use that header.

Comment: Forgive me for not understanding... I'll have to change the header of what? Should I make my link point to the PHP file that you wrote?

Comment: You want to change the HTTP header. They are a couple of ways to go about it. You can do it trough PHP or with the help your server e.g.: Apache, and NGiNX. To use the PHP script you just need to point to the  PHP script I gave you.

Comment: Excellent! That worked like a charm! I saved your php snippet into a file named `downloadimg.php` and changed my JavaScript to read:
`function savePhoto(){window.open("downloadimg.php");}`

Comment: Could this same script work with a JQuery `$.post()` command? I'm trying to pass a dataURL variable to the PHP, but it doesn't work when I call the php via `$.post()`, only when I do it via window.open